# how to change style of bootstrap tagsinput

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-tags-input

I have an input field with bootstrap tagsinput, the problem is when the tag is activated I don't have the box of the tag.

For example I have this :
[image]

And I want something like this :

[image]

showing that the tag python and java is activated with creating a little box.

I am using this style for my example :

```
 <style>



.bootstrap-tagsinput {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  color: #555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 100%;
  line-height: 22px;
  cursor: text;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput input {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0 6px;
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  max-width: inherit;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput.form-control input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: rgb(170, 36, 36);
  opacity: 1;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput.form-control input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #777;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput.form-control input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #777;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput input:focus {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag {
  margin-right: 2px;
  color: black;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"] {
  margin-left: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"]:after {
  content: "x";
  padding: 0px 2px;
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"]:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"]:hover:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}

</style>
```

Comment: Could you give the HTML or create a codepen that can be used to replicate the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding this :

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag {
  background: gray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0 6px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```